# Wrong DateTime Conversion in JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, type-conversion

I have a problem with a DateTime conversion. I have variables which represents a DateTime in milliseconds. If I print them I will get this values:

```
console.log(test1343[0][0].date);
console.log(test1343[0][1].date);
```

1475676478000

1475676471000

Now if I convert these values to an date:

```
console.log(new Date(test1343[0][0].date));
console.log(new Date(test1343[0][1].date));
```

I get:

Wed Oct 05 2016 16:07:58 GMT+0200

Wed Oct 05 2016 16:07:51 GMT+0200

Now if i convert these values to JSON:

```
console.log(temp1.toJSON());
console.log(temp2.toJSON());
```

I will get a time shift of two hours.

2016-10-05T14:07:58.000Z

2016-10-05T14:07:51.000Z

Can someone tell me how to delete this time shift?

Gz Markus

Comment: So what's the inner  `Date` function, are you calling the native `Date` twice ?

Comment: Just remove the inner Date function

Comment: Observe -> https://jsfiddle.net/jc0bozv2/

Comment: Thank you for the response that was the first error. But I have another error which you can see in my changed question